# program in C that reverse a string

Tags: c, arrays, string, scanf, reverse

I wrote a program in C that asks a user for his name and output the number of letters, and ask again the user if he wants his name to be reversed if his response is yes, the program output the reversed name. 
the problem is I don't know why I lose the first letter in the array name
you can try this code. I think scanf is the source of the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  char name[30],reponse[3],response[3]="yes",temp;
  int j,i,t=0,k;
  printf("would you share with us your name ? \n");
  scanf("%s",name);
  printf("so your name is %s\n",name);
  for(i=0;i<=30;i++){
    if(name[i]!='\0') t++ ;
    else break;
  }
  printf("the number of letters in your name is %d\n",t);
  printf("do you want your name to be scrumbled ?\n");
  scanf("%s",reponse);// I think the problem is here
  for(j=0;j < 3;j++){
    if(response[j]!=reponse[j]) break;
  }
  if(j==3){
    k = t/2;
    for(i=0; i<k;i++){
       temp=name[i];
       name[i]=name[t-i-1];
       name[t-i-1]=temp;
    }
    printf("your new name is %s hahaha ",name);
  }
  else printf("OK");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `response[3]="yes"` didn't issue a warning??

Comment: Having a variable named reponse as well as response is maintenance nightmare. You are shooting yourself in the foot

Comment: @Mohamed  You have to declare the variable reponse[3] as having at least four characters if you expect that the user will enter the string 'yes",

Comment: @VladfromMoscow you're right, but I don't understand what's this has to do with name array??

Comment: @Mohamed The terminating zero of the entered string "yes" stored in the variable reponse[3] overwrites the first character in the variable name. That is the variable name is stored by the compiler after the variable reponse[3]

Comment: @StoryTeller sorry I have this bad habit and I must get rid of it ASAP before my code become hundreds of lines

Comment: Good. You'd be doing yourself a huge favor, as well as any of your future collaborators. I certainly did a double take when I looked your code over.

Comment: thanks guys  and specially @VladfromMoscow for help I think I understand know what's wrong, scanf is a tricky function, never trust it. and from now I should always give a place to '\0'.

Comment: Always set limits on strings.  In scanf you can do `%3s` for example.

Comment: `i<=30` --> `i<30`

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is that when the user enters the string `"yes"` that is stored in the array `reponse[3]` then the terminating zero of the string overwrites the first character in the array `name`.  That is the compiler placed the variable `name` after the variable `reponse` in the memory.

You should declare the array `reponse` as having at least four characters and use the field length in the format specifier of the function scanf.

For example

```
char name[30],reponse[4],response[3]="yes",temp;
                     ^^^    

//...

scanf("%3s",reponse); 
      ^^^^
```

A more safe way to enter strings is to use standard C function `fgets`.

Comment: thank you I appreciate your help. this solution works

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` doesn't know how big your destination buffer is.  It will gladly read a one-million-character string into a five-byte buffer.  When it does this, it corrupts memory by writing data past the end of the destination array.  You need to explicitly tell `scanf` when to stop in order to avoid array overflows.  For example, `scanf("%8s", &var);` for an 8-byte buffer.

Your code appears to reinvent standard functions like `strlen` and `strncmp`.  Using the standard functions instead will make your life much easier.

Nitpick: you ask "would you share with us your name?", which is a 'yes' or 'no' question.  You then expect the user to type their name, not 'yes' or 'no'.  You should reword the question to ask for the name directly in order to avoid any possible confusion.

Comment: what you said is right and very useful, but in this case 'scanf("%3s",reponse)' doesn't seems to resolve the problem. it's better to  declare reponse[4] in order to store '\0'

Comment: @Mohamed actually, since it's a string literal, just use `const char* response = "yes"`.  No need to manually create an array for it.

Comment: @Mohamed - your code works for me if you make that scanf change (http://ideone.com/2LEW7X)